# Need Regular expression javascript to get all images

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string that contains html . The html has several img tags in it . I want to find **all** the img tags and have some kind of **collection** so that i can replace them with my code.

Does anybody has any idea.

I want it in **Javascript**

Comment: Regex is not the tool for this. jQuery would be able to do it out of the box - any chance of using that?

Comment: if i dont get collection then can i replace all of them with my predefined code

Comment: Yup, that is possible as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `collection`

Comment: a collection means list or possibly all the img ones in a array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var html_str = '...some images and other markup...';

var temp = document.createElement( 'div' );
temp.innerHTML = html_str;

var images = temp.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
```

...then loop over the images...

```
for( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
    images[ i ].className = "my_class";
}
```

What you actually need to do may change how your loop runs, but the above just adds a class, so it is just a normal `for` loop.

Note that at this point you're dealing with DOM elements, not markup. These elements can be added directly to the DOM.

Comment: @Petah: You don't know if the asker is using jQuery. What if some other library is loaded? Or what if this is the only JavaScript that is needed on the page? In both cases, it would be overkill to load the entire library.

Comment: Disagree totally, JQ is non conflicting, small, and normally even pre cached if using a CDN.

Comment: i find this one interesting . I am trying this :)

Comment: @Petah: jQuery is enormous compared to writing a few lines yourself, and just a bunch of superfluous code if you have a different library already loaded. jQuery does make it easy to use it alongside other libraries, but there are a couple potential dangers lurking in the background if you do (even if there's no conflict).

Comment: It takes less than 1 second to _transfer_ JQ, even on a 33KBps dial up modem. And you only have to do it once.

Comment: Also what are these dangers you speak of?

Comment: @Petah: Mainly the way jQuery stores data like event handlers, anything you give to `.data()`, or other various information. The only link between that data and your element is the *expando property* jQuery puts on an element. As long as you use jQuery to remove elements from the DOM, you're fine because jQuery looks up the data using the expando, and cleans it up. But if you've loaded another library, I'd say there's a good chance you're using it for some DOM manipulation. So if it is used to remove elements, that data isn't cleaned up, and you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Petah - Your calculation of less than 1 second for dial-up transfer is _way_ off. With the fastest dial-up modem (56Kbps - `bps` is _bits_-per-second NOT _bytes_-per-second), and one start and stop bit per byte transfered (10 bits/byte), it will take _15 seconds_ to transfer the 1.5.2 version of `jquery.min.js` (size = 85,924 bytes which is the version being used by this very page). The jQuery library is great if you need it, but please learn the power of core Javascript before you bring out any bigger hammers!

Answer (score 1):

If you used jQuery you could do something like:

```
var html = '<div><img src="bla" /></div>';
$(html).find('img');
```

If you want to replace all images you would do:

```
var html = '<div><img src="bla" /></div>';
$(html).find('img').replaceWith('<div>Image was here</div>');
```

Comment: @I.devries, absolutely no harm in jQuery here either.

Comment: Well, aside from the extra Http traffic and the parsing time for the browser when using jQuery, the poster doesn't ask for jQuery and it is all perfectly doable in plain javascript. I consider it harmful to include entire frameworks in your code for no reason at all.

Comment: @I.devries, Unless your target audience is from the 1990's then browser speed is not an issue for JQ. Also if you cant combine, or inline JQ, 1 extra HTTP request is not going to have any major effect on request time. The poster also did not specificly say no to JQ.

Comment: @I.devries, also, what harm comes from using JQ, may I ask.

Comment: JQ is no harm . the scope of the project is to use javascript. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This is regex pattern to take all image tag:

```
var pattern = /\<img .+?\/\>/ig;
```

**UPDATE**: sample is here http://jsbin.com/oxafab/edit#source

Comment: Can you elaborate the code little bit more, how it gets all the tags

Comment: - Convert your string to DOM element, then find img tag is a solution.
- Use Regex is another clear solution with me. See sample here http://jsbin.com/oxafab/edit#source